# Android widget loses variable on stand by

Tags: android, android-widget

I am developing a very basic widget for Android. My widget has a variable that keeps the users choices, it's declared as static. The problem is that after a while, I suspect after a long stand by, the widget get's somewhat emptied out and the static variable becomes empty. What is the the solution to save the state of my widget without losing the "history" of it's life? onSaveInstanceState onPause are not defined for AppWidgetProvider. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You may save it in `SharePreference`. Every time you want to use it, first check if your variable is not empty (null), if it is, then try to retrieve the saved version in `SharedPreferences`. Also, every time the variable is updated, save it into SharedPrefs.

```
if(variable==null){
   variable = getFromSharedPrefs();
}

// Use it further
```

Comment: I thought about that but when? on every update? wouldn't it me too heavy to continuously push a variable in SharedPrefs?

Comment: Yes it may, but at least you will be sure the value of variable won't be lost, so you won't be in stress that time to time your application may not work.

Comment: I did as you suggested but, a part from being slower, still when the process is killed or paused it loses variables.

Comment: It looses variables from SharedPreferences? That is something strange. Make sure you commit the changes every time the variable is updated.

Comment: I have rewritten the whole code I don't know where the problem was but well, not it seems to work fine. Thank you for your help